# Which function grows faster

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

> 2^(n/2+10 log n)

or

> 2^n?

I was doing an exercise in MIT OCW 6.006. It has a problem which states that later grows faster than the former. But I cant agree with the proof. I say that the former grows faster than the later. Could someone explain if I am wrong and let me know why. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be posted on [cs.se]

Comment: This isn't a programming question. But one way to prove it would be to "factor out" the `2^` and look at the difference `f(x) = x - (x/2 + 10log(x))` or `f(x) = x/2 - 10*log(x)`. I think you could convince yourself that `f(x)` is an increasing function for large enough `x`.

Comment: in CS, log is usually base 2, on most calculator I have seen, log is base ten (as I assumed in my answer below). (many use ln for base e). Still, which base changes only the crossover point, not the ultimate result.

Comment: See [this](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=oo-5Uu_LC8fAkQWNloHICg#q=2^x%2C2^%28x%2F2%2B10*log%28x%29)

Comment: exactly @POW is my doubt. 2^n =O(2^(n/2+10 log n)) right? we can see 2^(n/2+10 log n) as an upper bound to 2^n

Comment: @bks4line the other way around. `n` is upper bound for `(n/2+10logn)`. and also for `(0.99999n+1000000logn)`, for big enough (and all that's bigger) `n`s. see [this](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=oo-5Uu_LC8fAkQWNloHICg#q=x%2C(x%2F2%2B10*log(x)) (click on zoom out few times)

Comment: That graph is hard to follow past very small values. 
modify the link to factor out the exponentials, and you will see that while n/2+10 log n is bigger for a period, it does not stay that way.

Answer (score 7):

You could frame that differently by pulling out the exponent part, then just  ask which is bigger (n/2+10logn) or n. 
Here its clear the 2nd will be bigger whenever 10logn is less than half n.

That becomes true when n reaches about 30, so from then on, the second is bigger. (for log base 10)

---

Lets discuss log base 2 further and when might 10LogN be less than N/2?
Well, thats the same as asking when does logN become less than N/20

Loosely speaking, log_2 is the number of bits needed to describe a number in base 2. So:

- log_2(32) gives us 5.
- log_2(64) gives us 6.
- log_2(128) gives us 7.   <-- look here 128:7 is about 18:1
- log_2(256) gives us 8.
- log_2(512) gives us 9.
- log_2(1024) gives us 10.
- log_2(64000) gives us ~16.

Now we are looking for when the first value (32,64,128,etc) is more than 20 times the second. As you can see this would happens just past the 128/7 pair, and they rapid get much further apart.

Comment: I don't think "grows faster than" is the same as "is bigger than". For example, n+1 is bigger than n, but both (I would say) grow at the same rate.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, ok, well that depends on the log base, try base 10 and you will get my result. ps nice graphing link

Comment: @anonymous, fair point, I would think obvious from that point, but I suppose a little more could be added. You want maybe to take differentials?

Comment: @RichardPlunkett Ah, you're right, I'm so used to `log` denoting a binary logarithm that I hardly pay attention any more :-)

Comment: even is n is 30, the first is smaller than second @Richard. how could that even change? 10logn is greater than n/2 for any case right?

Comment: okay right @richard. but in Computer world we always consider Log base 2 right?

Comment: @bks4line No, for 10*logN is small than N/2 for almsot all values. Irrespective of base, but, apparaently you would like more on that issue?

Comment: ok, you need to be looking at/asking about O(logN) vs O(N). logN is far far smaller. logs are one of our slowest growing functions. And constant factors (10x, 0.5x) on either side make no difference beyond the small values.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett, i will clarify a doubt. what is growth? according to me,it is a graph where y co ordinate is the number of operations/steps(indirectly time required) vs total number of input elemnets (x coordinate). am i right? So a log N function slowly increases(no of steps) for the given set of input, As compared to N graph. again am i right?

Comment: @bks4line The growth of a function is how fast f(x) grows, as x grows, irrespective of what you call your axes and what they represent. But, yes, for CS O(f) calculations, we tend to care about the growth in either time (or operations) or space.

Comment: @bks4line + Vatline, yep